# java apache HC BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest vs BasicHttpRequest

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

Making a class that takes instructions (steps) from a data source and automates few HC (http://hc.apache.org Apache Http Client) actions.

Want to be able to carry out HTTP post, get and direct (like sending a JSON or XML/ soap message to a web server) calls.

Confused about when to use BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest vs BasicHttpReques what is the enclosing?
Right now I have steps to init the context, provide param values, the URL, method etc when i want to submit this is what I'm doing:

```
        HttpPost httpost = null;//todo correct method
        //HttpEntity resp = this.httpclient.e

        HttpEntityEnclosingRequest reqEntity1 = null;//use this
        HttpRequest reqEntity = new BasicHttpRequest(method, urls, httpVer );//or this?
        URL url = new URL(urls);
        String hostNm = url.getHost();
        int port = url.getPort();
        String sche = url.getProtocol();
        logger.info("scheme/ proto :" + sche);
        HttpHost  httpHost = new HttpHost (hostNm, port, sche);
        response = this.httpclient.execute(httpHost, reqEntity, localContext);
```

Question : use one or the other or have another attribute for enclosing or regular HttpRequest?

See

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpRequest.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP specification clearly defines only `POST` and `PUT` as methods which can enclose a request content body. Whether or not it is legal for other methods such as `GET` or `HEAD` to enclose a request body is subject to debate.

HttpCore follows strict interpretation of the HTTP specification and represent regular requests as `HttpRequest` which does not provide a method to set a content body. For methods such as `PUT` and `POST` it provides extended `HttpEntityEnclosingRequest` with extra methods for request entity manipulations.

Comment: thanks so if method is Post i need it. the enclosing is the body part. i guess all obvious for those more familiar with http protocol wording

Comment: i was going to post this on the HC user group but am glad you follow stack :-)