# org.apache.http.HttpRequest how to add a body

Tags: java, apache, soap, httprequest

I want to make a post request to a soap web service.

i did this:

```
private static HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    private static HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
HttpRequest requset = new BasicHttpRequest("POST",
                "/iOSS bla bla bla");
        requset.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic c21hcnQ2ODYzOnNtYXJ0Njg2Mw==");
        requset.addHeader("Content-Type",
                "multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; boundary=\"--=Part1=-- \"");
        requset.addHeader("SOAPAction", "");
```

I couldn't know how to add the body of the request. i didn't find the method for that

Kindly note that I am using `HttpRequest` to form the Http request, I am not using `HttpPost` to form a post request

could you help please

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419268/java-apache-hc-basichttpentityenclosingrequest-vs-basichttprequest) instead.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it uses `HttpPost` not `HttpRequest`

Comment: No, look at the answer. It suggests using `HttpEntityEnclosingRequest` instead of `HttpRequest`, which otherwise doesn't provide setters for a body.

Comment: But, really, you should be using `HttpPost` (or any of the related types).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Okay I will give it a try first to use `HttpPost`, and if no success, I will try using `HttpEntityEnclosingRequest` and come back to u. Do you know please any example about HttpPost?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't use HttpPost because I didn't know how to instaciate an object from it

Comment: [This first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188041/write-in-body-request-with-httpclient). There are various `HttpEntity` subtypes you can use (or write your own). Then just use `setEntity`. The link is a little outdated for how to create `HttpClient`. You have the more recent pattern in your sample code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in HttpPost(url) my problem is that I didn't know if I have to put the whole URL ? or just the url that comes after the host

Comment: I believe `HttpClient` allows you to do either. It provides an `execute` overload that accepts a single `HttpRequest` (which is a superinterface of `HttpPost`), where the URL should be absolute. It also provides an overload where you can provide an `HttpHost`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`HttpRequest`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) interface does not provide a method to set the corresponding message body. Neither does [`BasicHttpRequest`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpRequest.html)

You need to go one level deeper into the inheritance hierarchy and use [`HttpEntityEnclosingRequest`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html), which exposes a [`setEntity(HttpEntity)`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html#setEntity%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) method, and its default implementation [`BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html).

An `HttpEntity` more or less represents the http message body. The [javadoc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) states

> An entity that can be sent or received with an HTTP message.

There are a number of supported implementations, eg. `StringEntity`, `ByteArrayEntity`, `FileEntity`, etc. You can write your own if these aren't good enough.

---

Alternatively, I suggest you use the various `HttpXyz` classes that represent each method, eg. [`HttpPost`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html). These types already come with a `setEntity(HttpEntity)` method when appropriate (`HttpPost` has one, but an `HttpGet` doesn't because a GET request shouldn't need a body).

The [`HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) provides `execute(...)` method overloads which can accept `HttpRequest` objects, where the URI should be absolute, and others where you can also provide an `HttpHost` to resolve a path.